# jQuery highlight row based on header $_GET variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have small dashboard of recently added records and I want to highlight the table row based on a header $_GET variable.

I already have one header, called myVariable, so I propose using an &myVariable2 ?

```
index.php?**myVariable**=1&**myVariable2**=2
```

When this URL is visited, it highlights the row with the record of $myID.

How do I get jQuery to highlight the row (Background colour is fine) based on $myID (header)? If this isn't possible I can always add it into a variable and do something with jQuery.

I have the ID in a $variable, and need to highlight the row with that $variable. $row[variableID] in mysql.

Comment: How are you creating the table? Post the code for the table.

Comment: Just a simple while loop outputting all records in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
 $(".rows[data-id='<?php echo intval($_GET['highlight']); ?>']").css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

would be fine. Just add data-id to your `.rows` and change `$_GET['highlight']` to your one

Or instead of using php to get the query values, you can use javascript. See this question [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Instead of using php to get the query values, you can use javascript. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @Ragnar123: why? That's complicated and this one is even faster

Comment: Really don't understand this :P

Comment: How should I call this JS? what is .rows, the class of my row?

Comment: @genesisΨψ I just thought it would be appropriate to mention, that this issue could be solved using only javascript.

Comment: @Ragnar123: ah, okay. I'll link to that question. Thanks